# In django, can the .using('db') keyword take a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, multiple-databases

Example.objects.using('db').raw()

Instead of db could we have a variable that would correspond to the appropriate database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```py
my_db = "default"

Example.objects.using(my_db).get(pk=1)

my_db = "other_db_key_from_DATABASES"

Example.objects.using(my_db).get(pk=1)
```